# Modify higher bits of a variable in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a variable in C with a binary value of '10010100'
and I have another variable with the value is '1111'.
What I want to achieve is to keep bits 7,6,1,0 intact and insert the second variable in [5..2].

I have been told I could use a *mirror*. I have done some research and I cannot find the right answer.

If I move bits bitwise, I lose part of the content.

Comment: `v1 = (v1 & ~0x3C) | ((v2 & 0xF) << 2);` First zero the four bits, then isolate the new four bits, align and merge.

Comment: Q: I have been told I could use a mirror.  A: You *should* have been told to use a "bit mask", apply boolean operators ("and", "or" the appropriate bits) and shift operators (to position the bits).  See MikeCAT's reply below.  Be sure to "upvote" and "Accept" if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a mask (bitwise AND) to turn the part that should be replaced to the new values to zero.
2. Use bitwise OR to put the new value to the zeroed area.

```c
int a = 0x94; /* 10010100 */
int b = 0xf;  /* 1111     */

/*       do masking here                        */
/*       |               put the new value here */
/*       |               |                      */
/*       v               v                      */
a = (a & ~(0xf << 2)) | (b << 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to this problem is to clear the bits in the destination range with the `&` operator and an appropriate mask and set the bits from the second variable, shifted appropriately and potentially masked if it cannot be asserted that no other bits are set:

```
v1 = (v1 & ~(0xF << 2)) | ((v2 & 0xF) << 2);
```

If you know that `v2` has all bits set in the destination range, you can simplify as:

```
v1 = v1 | (0xF << 2);
```

Note however that `(v1 & ~(0xF << 2))` uses `int` arithmetics, which will extend the mask to the width of `v1` if its type is larger than `int`. But if the destination included the sign bit of type `int`, shifting a `1` bit into this position is undefined behavior. Using an explicit constant would not work either because it would have type `unsigned int` and extending it to the type of `v1` would also mask the high order bits of `v1` if its type is larger than `int`. For example:

```
/* replacing bits 31,30,29,28 */
long long v1 = 0x987654321;
int v2 = 0xF;
v1 = (v1 & ~(0xF << 28)) | ((v2 & 0xF) << 28);
// v1 is now 0x9F7654321 but really undefined behavior
v1 = (v1 & ~0xF0000000) | ((v2 & 0xF) << 28);
// v1 is now 0xF7654321 instead of 0x9F7654321
```

A similar issue occurs if `v2` has a type smaller than that of `v1` and must be shifted beyond its own length.

A safer approach would use constants with trailing type markers that match the type of `v1`, but this would still not work if a bit has to be shifted into the sign bit of type `long long`:

```
v1 = (v1 & ~(0xFLL << 60)) | ((v2 & 0xFLL) << 60); // undefined behavior
```

The general solution is to use `unsigned long long` constants:

```
v1 = (v1 & ~(0xFULL << 28)) | ((v2 & 0xFULL) << 28);
```

The behavior on obsolete non 2's complement architectures is non trivial and will be ignored.

Comment: C2x mandates 2's-complement arithmetic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: at last! hence the words *obsolete* and *will be ignored.* Note that `1 << 31` is still undefined behavior and `-1 >> 1` implementation defined.

Comment: Using function you can force unsigned arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would break it down into small pieces.

Note that the `0b` prefix is a non-standard extension, but commonly found on several compilers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t a = 0b10010100;
    uint8_t b = 0b00001111;
    
    uint8_t keep7610 = a & 0b11000011;     // Keep Bits 7, 6, 1, and 0. Set the others to 0
    uint8_t insertb = keep7610 | (b << 2); // Add in variable B at position 2-5
    
    printf("Final Answer: 0x%02X\n", insertb);
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5444KB
Final Answer: 0xBC
```

(`0xBC` translates as `0b10111100`, which is what I get when I follow your instructions manually)

Comment: Binary constants are in C++14, and will be in C2x.  So will "numeric punctuation", which will allow you to write `0b1001'0100` with one single quote in it — which makes ad hoc parsing of C++ code hard (and will make ad hoc parsing of C code hard too).

Answer (score 0):

Use functions!

```
unsigned replaceBits(unsigned val, int startBit, int nBits, unsigned newVal)
{
    unsigned mask = ((1UL << nBits) - 1) << startBit;

    //clear bits
    val &= ~mask;

    //set new value  (adding with mask makes sure that we will not change any other bits.
    val |= (newVal << startBit) & mask;
    
    return val;
}
```

You can also add some checks to make sure that parameters have valid values.

Example:

https://godbolt.org/z/zofKqofx1

Comment: any comment silent DV-ter?